# I'm trying to run Steam but 32-bit libraries are missing

Tags: steam

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libXrandr.so.2
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
libpango-1.0.so.0
libfreetype.so.6
libfontconfig.so.1
libgobject-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
libcairo.so.2
libpango-1.0.so.0
libfreetype.so.6
libfontconfig.so.1
libgobject-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libXi.so.6
libasound.so.2
libXrender.so.1
libnss3.so
libnssutil3.so
libsmime3.so
libplc4.so
libnspr4.so
libdbus-1.so.3
libpng12.so.0
libcups.so.2
libgcrypt.so.11
```

Comment: Considering that it says "may" not run, can you try just running it anyway and see if it works?

Comment: @MatrixFrog with 13.10 this error is blcking, and after installing 14.04 it is not ;)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/264600/170741

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 64-bit Ubuntu, if so, try this:

Open up a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

A reboot may be required

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the foreign arch i386 to make i386 packages available.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6-i386
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and I have **64-bit** Ubuntu 13.10.
[Erick's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/257581/32413) does not work for me now because **ia32-libs** is not available anymore.

So I installed **Ubuntu 14.04**, the same problem occurs.
So I installed the available "32 libraries":

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install lib32z1 
$ sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 
$ sudo apt-get install lib32bz2-1.0
```

Now launching Steam there is this warning:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
```

These libraries are not available, but **Steam runs fine on 14.04 for me even with this warning**.