# why can't I get steam on Ubuntu

Tags: steam, chromebook

So I have an acer c7 chromebook and I have chrubuntu 13.10 I think and its 64 bit and I installed steam from the software center but when I open it up it tell me I have to install a package and when I type in my pass word and hit enter it says:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6
```

Comment: The answer is here :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/260813/trying-to-install-steam-error-you-are-missing-the-following-32-bit-libraries-a

Answer (score 0):

From terminal

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

once done should work if you get a library error

```
sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf
```

**/usr/lib32**

**(you may need never had to use this line)**
**/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> **save**

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Steam should now work properly from this point on..

Comment: That didn't work :(...... any other ideas?

Comment: @user255629, please elaborate: what happens now? Does error message change?

Comment: It told me that the packege I was trying to install was out of date or doesn't exist and gave me this list of suggestions

Comment: these were the suggestions: However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

Comment: and for the first two lines it says those are unknown options