# In Software Center some software is not found

Tags: software-center, 14.04

I have installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.04. Then I started to install some new software. But when I tried to see the description of some software, the following type of message was displayed.

> **Not found**
> There isn’t a software package called “steam” in your current software sources.

The install button was also not available. And the software which I am able to install shows the following message in the review section.

> No network connection. Connect to the internet to see more

But I am connected to the internet and I have installed some software from the Software Center already.

Comment: Try to install the package from terminal. In some cases Terminal does rather than SC.

Answer (score 19):

For 64 bit Ubuntu systems only, add the i386 architecture before running all the below commands,

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

First enable multiverse repository,

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

Update all the repositories

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install steam package

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

#### How did i know

```
$ apt-cache policy steam
N: Unable to locate package steam
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ apt-cache policy steam
steam:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.0.0.45-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:1.0.0.45-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
```

Comment: The first gives following out put.

" 'multiverse' distribution component is already enabled for all sources."

Comment: good, then proceed to the next step. Make sure that your internet connection is working on terminal.

Comment: The second command gave the following output                                       "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
"

Comment: The third command gave the following output  "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
" Internet connection was always on during tasks.

Comment: close the software-center first. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

Comment: Simply issuing `sudo apt-get install steam` worked for me.