# Help with linux based gaming

Tags: games

I am new to Ubuntu and linux in general. I am an avid gamer that used to play off of steam on windows, and am now finding that steam doesn't work and I cannot play any non- linux games. I am wondering if there is any way to play these games without going back to windows

Comment: Steam works fine on Ubuntu.  If you are having issues, open a terminal window and type `steam`.  Edit your question and include any error messages you get.

Comment: You can install Steam for Windows and use that, but you will not have good performance.

Comment: "non-linux games" already answers your question. If you want "steam doesn't work" provide something for us to help you with.

Comment: when I try to use steam it says im missing libGL.so.1 32-bit libraries

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the missing libGL.so.1 32-bit libraries please check this thread:

[Trying to install Steam ERROR: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: not](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260813/trying-to-install-steam-error-you-are-missing-the-following-32-bit-libraries-a)

Sees like creating a link is the way to go:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib
```

Good luck