# How to install Steam on Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: steam

I know literally nothing about linux/ubuntu, but I have linux activated and I downloaded it through steam. When I click on it to open it it gives me the message: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6 Could someone help?

Comment: Steam installation should be as easy as `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install steam` . Please edit your question and tell us what you've been trying to do and please copy-paste the entire error(s) you're getting. Kindly format errors as `code` and retain all line breaks, so we can parse it.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/260813/trying-to-install-steam-error-you-are-missing-the-following-32-bit-libraries-a

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to install Steam ERROR: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: not](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260813/trying-to-install-steam-error-you-are-missing-the-following-32-bit-libraries-a)

Answer (score 0):

Open a console or terminal and type:

```bsh
sudo apt update
# enter your password when prompted
sudo apt install steam
```

After the installation, run steam from the start menu. It might ask you to install even more libraries.